# Read file to slow when refreshing page multiple times

Tags: php, wordpress, delay, readfile

`$myfile = fopen("lastupdate.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
echo fread($myfile,filesize("lastupdate.txt"));
fclose($myfile);`

This is my php code in my wordpress Plugin. When I update the Website 20 times it tooks around 20 Seconds to load the single page. Without these 3 lines of code it only tooks 1 second to load the page.

Can you tell me why it is so slow ?

I want to use the textfile to store a string (2000 chars). 
In my tests there is only a "hello world" inside and it still tooks one second. How can i resolve this problem ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to get the contents of a file into a string, use [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) as it has much better performance

[file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) is the preferred way to read the contents of a file into a string. It will use memory mapping techniques if supported by your OS to enhance performance.

In current context,

```
<?php
  $myfile = fopen("lastupdate.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
  echo fread($myfile,filesize("lastupdate.txt"));
  fclose($myfile);
?>
```

Can be replaced with  [readfile()](http://php.net/readfile),this will read the file and send it to the browser in one command

```
<?php
   readfile("lastupdate.txt");
?>
```

This is essentially the same as

```
<?php
   echo file_get_contents("lastupdate.txt");
?>
```

except that [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)  may cause the script to crash for large files, while [readfile()](http://php.net/readfile) won't.